# 29 - 1 = 30 how?

Tags: lateral-thinking

How is 29 - 1 = 30?

If also

14 - 1 = 15

11 - 1 = 10

9 - 1 =10.

Hint:

> Guess the answer and be like Minerva

Comment: You mean if I guess the answer I am.... imaginary.

Comment: I think the hint is confusing.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans your comment (particularly the word before 'equivalent') is kind of a spoiler. It made me realise the answer, and I hadn't even looked at the hint.

Comment: How about `how = 2`?

Comment: Instead of "-1" it should have been "-i". It would have led to interesting proofs and been more correct.

Comment: @AmruthA "like Athena" might as well be "like Buddha" or "like Sophocles" or something.  The point is that it's like something that is like Athena, not like Athena herself, and that's confusing.

Comment: Athena and Minerva are both counterparts of each other ..one in Rome other in Greek .. @jamesdlin

Comment: @AmruthA I am very much aware of that.  The point remains that your hint requires *two* leaps (Athena => Minerva => Roman) which is misleading, and there's no basis for making that jump.  The question would be better without the hint.

Comment: @jamesdlin Maybe not two jumps. I think you can go "Greek Numerals => Roman Numerals" on the off chance one doesn't know who Minerva is. Greek numerals, and games you can play with them, are almost if not more popular and famous than Roman ones.

Comment: @AmruthA why is there a new open bounty on this post when there's already an accepted answer?

Comment: @El-Guest That is what I was wondering too

Comment: @ZaniXu  i wanted this question to be highest viewed question..

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Explanation:

> If you're using Roman numerals, you can remove I (one) from the representations of the numbers before the minus sign to get the representation of the numbers in the right.

29 - 1 = 30

> XXIX - I = XXX

14 - 1 = 15

> XIV - I = XV

11 - 1 = 10

> XI - I = X

9 - 1 =10

> IX - I = X

Comment: If this is actually the answer, then the hint is misleading - it should have been about Minerva. :)

Comment: @fluffy " like Athena " not Athena ..counterpart for Minerva in Greek ..

Comment: @AmruthA but you're saying the answerer will be like Athena, or at least that's what the statement implies.

Comment: @AmruthA My point being that the ancient Greeks didn't use Roman numerals.  (Arguably Romans didn't use Roman numerals the same way we do either, though.)

Comment: Well, Athena was born by splitting Zeus' head. So maybe it's something like "you'll facepalm so hard when the answer comes to you". Not much of a hint, though, if it is...

Comment: Good luck on getting 8 more upvotes!

Answer (score 46):

$$9 - 1 = 10 = 11 - 1,$$ 
thus

$$29 - 1 = 20 + 9 - 1 =\\
= 20 + 11 - 1 = 31 - 1 = 30.$$

**Edit**

Or just using that $9-1 = 10$

$$ 29 - 1 = 20 + 9-1 = 20 + 10 = 30.$$

Comment: Why did you(?) vote for delete?

Comment: This is probably the best thing I've seen all day. I can't believe it only has 2 upvotes.

Comment: I was surpriced to see that no one else had posted it. Thanks! @Kröw

Comment: @Olba12- Good answer!

Comment: @M.Herzkamp It is given right there in the question that 11 - 1 = 10.

Comment: Can you make the assumption that 29 = 20 + 9?

Comment: Imagine That you have set $X$ with two operations, $\{+,-1\}$ think of the $+$ as we normally do, and $-1$ as an operator who is defined by the last digit in a number. $29-1 = (2\cdot 10^1 + 9\cdot 10^0)-1 = 2\cdot 10^1 +(9-1)$. Now $(9-1)$ is defined to be $10$. Thus $-1$ maps it to $10$ and $2\cdot10^1$ maps to itself. Then for instance, what is $28-1$? Well, $(28)-1=(10 + 9+9)-1 = 10 + (9 + 9)-1 = 10 + 9-1 + 9-1 = 30$. You asked a **really** good question. I tried to answer it.It is far from perfect. Obviously I didnt think of this, when I came up with the answer to the question. @UKMonkey

Comment: @UKMonkey Given that the question is tagged 'mathematics', I think it should be fine to assume common mathematical conventions (except, of course, when it contradicts the puzzle itself, for example 29 - 1 = 30).

Comment: Now you can. ;)@M.Herzkamp

Comment: Okay, before the edit, there was still the issue of 31-1 = 30, which was definitely not provided ;-) After the edit you use associativity of + and - (i.e. (x+y)-1 = x + (y-1) ) of which I am not convinced yet...

Comment: I decieded that $-1$ would be a linear operator. I also defined it to map $20$ to $20$ and $9$ to $10$. If you look in my comment above tagged to UKMonkey. So its basically linearity. @M.Herzkamp

Comment: You cannot build a consistent operation that way which fulfills the three equations above. Your assumption is (x+y)-1 = x-1 + y-1. Using 9-1 = 10 and 11-1 = 10 you get 2-1 = 0, which leads to 1-1 + 1-1 = 0, so 1-1 should be zero as well. But then any number must be mapped to 0, which contradicts the equations given in the puzzle.

Comment: How did you get $2-1 = 0$? If you wrote it as $2-1=(11-9)-1 = 11-1 - 9-1 = 0$ Then I dont agree with you. @M.Herzkamp

Comment: 10 = 11-1 = (9+2)-1 = 9-1 + 2-1 = 10 + 2-1. Since the "+" is our usual plus, and both sides need to be identical, it follows that 2-1 = 0

Comment: @M.Herzkamp Yes, that is correct, and then one (I) must find a better way to define -1.

Comment: Lets say you have an $x$ then we look at the expressions, $x - (10\cdot k + 9), x-(10\cdot k + 11) , x - (10\cdot k+ 14)$ where $k$ is natural number, and $-$ in this expression is normal minus. Then let $y$ be the smallest, must be positive or $0$, of the three expressions. Given $x$ assume for clarity that $x-(10\cdot k +9)$ was the smallest. Then we define $x-1$ as $x-1 = (x-9) + 9-1 = (x-9) + 10 = x + 10.$ Then $28-1 = (28-14) + 14-1 = 29$. @M.Herzkamp

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your definition... But you need to keep in mind, that it must also be valid for the three cases given in the question!

Comment: It is, because $14-1 = (14-14) +14-1 = 0+15= 15$, $9-1= (9-9)+ 9-1= 0 + 10=10$, $11-1=(11-11)+11-1$=0+10=10$. You have to seperate normal minus from the operator $-1$.@M.Herzkamp

Answer (score 23):

I suppose you could always round the answer to the nearest multiple of 5, although that has nothing to do with Athena.

$$\begin{align}
29-1&=28 \xrightarrow{\text{rounds to }}30\\
14-1&=13 \xrightarrow{\phantom{\text{________}}} 15\\
11-1&=10 \xrightarrow{\phantom{\text{________}}} 10\\
9-1 &= \phantom08 \xrightarrow{\phantom{\text{________}}} 10\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: yup, that's what I thought it was.  The puzzle isn't clear enough to eliminate this possibility.

Answer (score 19):

This is mathematically true in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $\bmod 2$:

$$\begin{align}
29 - 1 \equiv 30 \equiv 0 \pmod 2\\
14 - 1 \equiv 15 \equiv 1 \pmod 2\\
11 - 1 \equiv 10 \equiv 0 \pmod 2\\
9 - 1 \equiv 10 \equiv 0 \pmod 2\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: +1 I had similar thoughts, thinking the arithmetic was in the field of 2 elements {0,1}

Answer (score 5):

This is inspired by/alternative to [Olba12's nice answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52525/4828):

$$\begin{align}
30
&= 10 + 10 + 10\\
&= (11 - 1) + (11 - 1) + (9 - 1)\\
&= 31 - 3\\
&= 31 - 2 - 1\\
&= 29 - 1
\end{align}$$

Hence: $29 - 1 = 30$.

Comment: Like Olba12, you cannot mix the "$-$" in the puzzle with our usual minus sign. They behave rather differently!

Comment: The minus sign in my solution is not at all contradicting the minus sign in the puzzle. I take the minus sign in the puzzle to define a new operator, so that in the cases given in the question, it gives those results. In other cases, it behaves like the usual minus sign. The plus operator works as usual, since the question doesn't say anything about it. The puzzle is tagged mathematics, so we can assume basic mathematical conventions and rules, except when the puzzle explicitly overrides them.

Comment: By your definition you have 10 = 9 - 1 = 10 - 1 - 1 = 10 - 2 = 8, which is a contradiction.

Comment: You should first question the OP who came up with this stupid puzzle and tagged it Mathematics. 10 = 9 - 1 is already a contradiction, everything else you "deduce" from it will be likely to be a contradiction anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach that doesn't require redefining ‘$-$’ as a string operation, rather than a mathematical one:

$$\begin{align}
29 - 1\ (\text{base}\ 11) &= 30\ (\text{base}\ 10)\\
14 - 1\ (\text{base}\ 12) &= 15\ (\text{base}\ 10)\\
11 - 1\ (\text{base}\ 10) &= 10\ (\text{base}\ 10)\\
9 - 1\ (\text{base}\ 10) &= 10\ (\text{base}\ 8)
\end{align}$$

I like the OP's intent better, though. It's a clever puzzle.

Comment: How does this work? Do we just choose any random base at each step?

Comment: not a random base, but just cherrypick the one that fits. Arbitrary ≠ random.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, this requires an arbitrary base at each step -- which is why I like the OP's solution better, despite the requirement that one redefine the meaning of '-'.  
  
In my defense, I based this solution off the title of the puzzle: "29 - 1 = 30, how?" Which implied a single case. When I saw multiple cases, I realized the solution wasn't good.  
  
Now, if the cases had been presented like this:  
  
14 - 1 = 15  
29 - 1 = 30  
11 - 1 = 10  
  
the 'different bases' solution would make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is a cheeky answer.

Assume the usual rules of arithmetic and logic.

We are told that $9 - 1 = 10$, that is, $8 = 10$, which is a contradiction.

By the rules of logic, since we have derived a contradiction, we can now [derive anything else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) (like 'magic', cf the storybook character Minerva), such as, that

$29 - 1 = 30$.

QED

Answer (score 0):

It is just the '-' operator has changed its semantics to compute sum of its operands.

Comment: '`11-1=10`' does not work here: `11+1=12`, not `10`.